# PHP APC Potential Cache Slam Averted for Key

Tags: php, apache2, apc

I'm receiving this error while trying to use `apc_store()`. I googled it and saw that this was **APC timebomb bug** and saw some fixes which suggested adding `apc.slam_defense = Off;` to php.ini.

I need to know whether this has happened because of a programming error, and if yes, how to fix it.

This is the code segment:

```
if ($data = apc_fetch("foo")) {
    $an_array = $data;
} else {
    /* couple of lines */

    apc_store("circles", $an_array); // This is where I get the error
}
```

This script will be called frequently in my deployed system.

I hope I've provided enough info

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since APC 3.1.3, it seems there is a bug (http://pecl.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=16814),  warning are made when slam defense is at on and when you try to write a key that already exists.
Does not seem to be fixed yet.

Answer (score 28):

Setting `apc.write_lock = 1` and `apc.slam_defense = 0` in `php.ini` should fix the problem.

Comment: Explanation: apc.write_lock effectively deprecates the slam_defence.

Answer (score 5):

Last versions of APC seems to resolve problem, you can update APC with PECL

```
pecl upgrade apc
```

Answer (score 2):

These instructions will vary based on how PHP is installed.

But, in your `/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/extensions.ini` file (or `apc.ini`, or `php.ini`) after you have added your `extension=apc.so` you can disable the slam defense

For example, this is my configuration that I use.

```
[apc]
apc.enabled=1
apc.shm_size=48M
apc.num_files_hint=10000
apc.user_entries_hint=10000
apc.max_file_size=5M
apc.stat=1
apc.enable_cli=On
apc.write_lock = 1 
apc.slam_defense = 0 # <----- This is the Important Setting
```